# Whether null value is stored on B + tree in MySQL？

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

mysql 5.7 innodb

EXPLAIN SELECT a FROM `test` WHERE a IS NULL;

a can be null and a is normal index；
we can see:
Extra info: Using where;Using index;
this meaning index store null value?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAg4D.png)

Comment: Yes, NULL is a value (representing some variation of “no value”). As such it must be stored somewhere. This somewhere is the same place non-NULL values are stored, per the column-type and relevant indices. There is no (super special) magic.

Comment: sure,i do a test.Column a in the table has 90% null value，it also use index instead of scanning Full table. if index not store null value,scan full table maybe a excellent solution. am i right??

Comment: i am wrong .EXPLAIN SELECT a FROM test WHERE a IS NULL;extra infor: Using where;Using index; Indicates the number of queries that need to be returned to the table through where condition as well as index. if  index store null value . why Return table query?? it can prove index not store null value???

Answer (score 2):

In analyzing indexing, think of `NULL` as "just another value".

Your particular `SELECT` does not do much.  It will do an "index scan" since all the columns needed (just `a`) are in the `INDEX inx_a (a)` (which you apparently have).  That is, the index is "covering".  It should not need a "full index scan" (looking at all 'rows').

Yes `NULL` values will come first in the index; it should perform an "index scan" something like:

1. Dive into the index's BTree at the beginning.
2. Read 'rows' until it hits something other than `NULL`; deliver `a`.

There are cases where the Optimizer will eschew an obvious `INDEX` and simply do a "table scan", but that does not seem to be the case here.  For example, because most of the rows have `a IS NULL`, the following is very likely to ignore the index and do a table scan:

```
SELECT a,b FROM t WHERE a IS NULL
```

OTOH, `INDEX(a,b)` would be a "covering index" and it should do a "range scan" in the index.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, *as text not image*, if you wish to discuss this further.

Comment: hello，my sql ，i also think  the index is "covering"，but explain  info：Using where;Using index，instead of Using index，it whether meaning index not include null？

Comment: `Using index` means "covering index", which means that all the columns in the `SELECT` are found in the one `INDEX`.

Comment: @RickJames just to confirm, by `Yes NULL values will come first in the index`, do you mean the NULL value is the smallest value in each B+ tree node? Basically, I 'd like to understand how the NULL values is stored physically in the index B+ tree. Thanks.

Comment: @Alfred - Yes, that is how I understand the layout of the BTree.  Hence `WHERE x IS NULL` has the same performance characteristics as `WHERE x = 123`.  (I don't think being "first" or "smallest" ever factors into anything.)